# Not possible to launch Gennymotion emulator in Windows

Tags: android

- I have downloaded and installed the Gennymotion Software
- I followed proper steps ...

**I dont know whether the settings i am making error to configure it properly ....**

Gennymotion software is installed but it is not launching !

---

*After installing G.Motion i get like below*

[image]

### After i click ok

[image]

**Then a error screen pops like this !**

[image]

How to resolve this error ?

### Not able to launch Genymotion emulator for the first time after configuring the settings

---

Comment: Try to use "Run as Administrator" property settings to execute Genymotion application under Windows 7/8. I suspect it wants to access privileged functions but it fails under a non-admin account.

Comment: Other than that, please match your system setup against Genymotion's requirements as laid out in their online user guide.

Comment: I can see the emulator running in Oracle VM console but ... gennymotion stops ! .... i am usin windows-7 , 32-bit. i have no sub users. I am logged a s admin

Comment: About VirtualBox, are you using the one installed by Genymotion or is it separately installed? If the latter, check the requirement VirtualBox version >= 4.1. Otherwise, try to totally removing both Genymotion and VirtualBox and reinstall Genymotion (let Genymotion install VirtualBox using its installer)

Comment: Ok, one thing about running a virtual device via Genymotion application rather than Oracle VM Virtual Box is that it requires your system's video card to support OpenGL v2.0. Forget about running it using older integrated video chip! Otherwise, player.exe will fail miserably...Another requirement, your system/processor must be capable of supporting Intel's VT-x or AMD's AMD-V virtualization. Otherwise, it defaults to 1.

Comment: mY SYSTEM DOSEN'T HAVE A VIDEO CARD..... It has only Intel HD graphics ... I think it might not support OpenGL .... Yes i think this is exactly the same reason .... why i am not able to run .... otherwise i have triple checked all other things .... !

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I was not running Oracle VirtualBox.
Start Oracle VirtualBox first then run the emulator.

Comment: I did the steps .... still have the same error .... do i need to set any preferences in Oracle Virtual BOX before launching the emulator ..

Answer (score 0):

I had to run both Virtual Box and Genymotion as admin (right click>run as admin) and then it worked fine. Just being logged in as admin was not enough since it needs admin-ok for the C-drive